# Scala--How to get the same part of the two RDDS?

Tags: scala, join, rdd

There are two RDD:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List(("aaa", 1), ("bbb", 4), ("ccc", 3)))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List(("aaa", 2),  ("bbb", 5), ("ddd", 2)))
```

If I want to join those by the first field and get the result like:

```
List(("aaa", 1,2), ("bbb",4 ,5))
```

What should I code?Thx!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `join` the RDDs and `map` the result to the wanted data structure:

```
val resultRDD = rdd1.join(rdd2).map{
  case (k: String, (v1: Int, v2: Int)) => (k, v1, v2)
}
// resultRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[53] at map at <console>:32

resultRDD.collect
// res1: Array[(String, Int, Int)] = Array((aaa,1,2), (bbb,4,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

As both the `RDDs` of the type `RDD[(String, Int)]` you can simply use `join` to join these two `RDDs` and you will get `RDD[(String, (Int, Int))]` . Now as you want `List[(String, (Int, Int))]` you need to collect joined RDD **(it is not recommended if joined RDD is huge)** and convert it to `List`. Try following code,

```
val rdd1: RDD[(String, Int)] = sc.parallelize(List(("aaa", 1), ("bbb", 4), ("ccc", 3)))
val rdd2: RDD[(String, Int)] = sc.parallelize(List(("aaa", 2), ("bbb", 5), ("ddd", 2)))

//simply join two RDDs
val joinedRdd: RDD[(String, (Int, Int))] = rdd1.join(rdd2)

//only if you want List then collect it (It is not recommended for huge RDDs)
val lst: List[(String, (Int, Int))] = joinedRdd.collect().toList

println(lst)

//output
//List((bbb,(4,5)), (aaa,(1,2)))
```